# Table editor via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Perhaps we all worked with phpMyAdmin, namely with a table. Surely you noticed that by clicking on a cell, the cell becomes an input. I decided to write my plug-in (task), but I ran into two problems (others have not noticed yet). How to solve them?

1st problem:
By clicking on a cell, the cell becomes an input with the original cell data. Suppose I need to change not completely, but in part. To do this, I need to put the cursor in the right place, but the cell data is erased. I understand why this is, but I do not know how to decide

2nd problem:
I do not know how to make it so that when another cell is clicked, the old input becomes a cell, that is, if you click on all cells, they all become input'om.

HTML

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").workTables();
});


//Чтобы избежать возможных конфликтов имен, обернем наш код в следующую конструкцию
(function($) {
  /* Чтобы добавить новый метод в объект jQuery, 
   * необходимо добавить функцию с его реализацией в объект jQuery.fn. 
   * В нашем плагине нужно организовать один метод,
   * который будет работать с ячейками таблицы
   * Назовем его так же как и сам плагин — workTables
   */
  $.fn.workTables = function() {
    // this - это то, на что кликнули (в данном случае)
    $(this).click(function() {

      if (this.nodeName == "TD") {

        var cell = $(this).text();

        $(this).empty();

        var input = '<input type="text" value="' + cell + '">';

        $(this).append(input);

        $('input').focus().select();


      }

      /*  один из примера решения при помощи prompt
          if (this.nodeName == "TD") {
              var cell = $(this).text();
          
              var value = prompt("Введите новое значение ячейки", cell);
              
              var question = confirm('Вы уверены, что хотите обновить содерживое ячейки?');
          
              if (question == true) {
                  $(this).text(value);
              }
          }
          //$(this).css('color', '#ff0000');
      */
    });

    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == "13") {
        cell = $('input').val();
        $('input').remove();
        $(this).text(cell);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.workTables.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Понедельник</th>
    <th>Вторник</th>
    <th>Среда</th>
    <th>Четверг</th>
    <th>Пятница</th>
    <th>Суббота</th>
    <th>Воскресенье</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 пара 8:00 - 9:35</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Система технико-экономического анализа деятельности организации</td>
    <td>Программная и системная инженерия</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 пара 9:45 - 11:20</td>
    <td>Система технико-экономического анализа деятельности организации</td>
    <td>Веб-технологии</td>
    <td>Система технико-экономического анализа деятельности организации</td>
    <td>Программная и системная инженерия</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Элективные курсы по физической культуре</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3 пара 12:10 - 13:45</td>
    <td>Бизнес-аналитика и статистика</td>
    <td>Разработка приложений с использованием Oracle</td>
    <td>Элективные курсы по физической культуре</td>
    <td>Программная и системная инженерия</td>
    <td>Документирование создания информационных систем</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 пара 13:55 - 15:30</td>
    <td>Бизнес-аналитика и статистика</td>
    <td>АИС в производстве</td>
    <td>Эконометрика</td>
    <td>Проектирование информационных систем</td>
    <td>Бизнес-аналитика и статистика</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5 пара 16:10 - 17:45</td>
    <td>Эконометрика</td>
    <td>Разработка приложений с использованием Oracle</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Проектирование информационных систем</td>
    <td>Эконометрика</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6 пара 17:55 - 19:30</td>
    <td>Эконометрика</td>
    <td>АИС в производстве</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Проектирование информационных систем</td>
    <td>Документирование создания информационных систем</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7 пара 20:05 - 21:40</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems.

You need to check inside the click handler if the `<td>` already has an input. Otherwise it will empty the existing one and there is no text to add to the second input  it adds. That is why all the selected text is disappearing

To undo the others add an `editable` class on the input and look for other cells in parent table that have such an input.

The following cleans up those issues as well as improves the code a bit

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").workTables();
});


//Чтобы избежать возможных конфликтов имен, обернем наш код в следующую конструкцию
(function($) {
  /* Чтобы добавить новый метод в объект jQuery, 
   * необходимо добавить функцию с его реализацией в объект jQuery.fn. 
   * В нашем плагине нужно организовать один метод,
   * который будет работать с ячейками таблицы
   * Назовем его так же как и сам плагин — workTables
   */
  $.fn.workTables = function() {
    // this - это то, на что кликнули (в данном случае)

    // "this" in plugin is the whole collection of elements in selector
    // loop over whole collection and isolate individual elements
    // "return this" makes the plugin chainable with other jQuery methods
    return this.each(function() {

      var $td = $(this);

      $td.click(function() {
        // don't do anything if cell has an editable input in it
        if ($td.find('input.editable').length) {
          return
        }
        // revert any other cells that have <input> back to text
        $td.closest('table').find('td').has('input.editable').text(function() {
          return $(this).find('input.editable').val()
        });

        var cell = $td.text();

        var $input = $('<input>', {
          class: "editable",
          value: cell
        });

        $td.html($input);

        $input.focus().select();

      });

      $td.keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == "13") {
          var $input = $td.find('input.editable')
          if ($input.length) {
            $td.text($input.val());
          }
        }
      });
    })
  };
})(jQuery);
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.workTables.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Понедельник</th>
    <th>Вторник</th>
    <th>Среда</th>
    <th>Четверг</th>
    <th>Пятница</th>
    <th>Суббота</th>
    <th>Воскресенье</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 пара 8:00 - 9:35</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Система технико-экономического анализа деятельности организации</td>
    <td>Программная и системная инженерия</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2 пара 9:45 - 11:20</td>
    <td>Система технико-экономического анализа деятельности организации</td>
    <td>Веб-технологии</td>
    <td>Система технико-экономического анализа деятельности организации</td>
    <td>Программная и системная инженерия</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Элективные курсы по физической культуре</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3 пара 12:10 - 13:45</td>
    <td>Бизнес-аналитика и статистика</td>
    <td>Разработка приложений с использованием Oracle</td>
    <td>Элективные курсы по физической культуре</td>
    <td>Программная и системная инженерия</td>
    <td>Документирование создания информационных систем</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 пара 13:55 - 15:30</td>
    <td>Бизнес-аналитика и статистика</td>
    <td>АИС в производстве</td>
    <td>Эконометрика</td>
    <td>Проектирование информационных систем</td>
    <td>Бизнес-аналитика и статистика</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5 пара 16:10 - 17:45</td>
    <td>Эконометрика</td>
    <td>Разработка приложений с использованием Oracle</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Проектирование информационных систем</td>
    <td>Эконометрика</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6 пара 17:55 - 19:30</td>
    <td>Эконометрика</td>
    <td>АИС в производстве</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Проектирование информационных систем</td>
    <td>Документирование создания информационных систем</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7 пара 20:05 - 21:40</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```